# Using variables in MongoDB update statement

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to use a variable as the field name in an update statement and it is not working at all, any suggestions?

for example:

```js
COLLECTIONNAME.update(
    { _id: this._id },
    { $set: { VARIABLE1 : VARIABLE2 } }
);
```

actual code:

```js
 'blur .editable' : function () {
      var target = event.currentTarget.value;
      var field = event.currentTarget.name;
      field = ' " ' + field + ' " ';
      Hostings.update( { _id: this._id },{ $set: { field : target } } );
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
'blur .editable' : function () {
  var target = event.currentTarget.value;
  var field = event.currentTarget.name;

  var obj = {};
      obj[field] = target;
  Hostings.update( { _id: this._id },{ $set: obj } );
}
```

Javascrip objects can be accessed two ways:

```
object.attribute
```

or

```
object["attribute"]
```

if you use the second method you can access it with a variable

Comment: beautiful! I just had to remove this line: field = ' " ' + field + ' " '; and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: `Hostings.update( { _id: this._id },{ $set: { [field]: target } } );` Would also work

Comment: How does `[]`work internally? Does it enforce mongo to use the `key` from outside the anonymous function? Why is it not needed for the `value`
?

Answer (score 5):

As per [L. Norman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7969573/l-norman)'s comment, I find using the `[]` for the field value works instead

```
collection = "my_collection"
db.getCollection(collection).find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    var new_field = "new_field";
    var new_value = "new_value";

    db.getCollection(collection).update({_id: doc._id}, 
        {$set: {[new_field] : new_value}}) 
})
```

Comment: This was the simplest solution that worked.  Placing the field value in [ ] was the solution to the same issue I was having.

Answer (score 1):

for your query
 `COLLECTIONNAME.update( { _id: this._id },{ $set: { VARIABLE1 : VARIABLE2 } } );` 
mongodb will take value of VARIABLE2 but it will consider "VARIABLE1" to be a field in the document.

For passing a variable whose value is a field name:

you will have to create a javascript object and use it as follows:

```
var obj={};
obj[VARIABLE1] = VARIABLE2; //where VARIABLE1 and VARIABLE2 are getting values from elsewhere earlier
```

If you want to have multiple fields this way, just add it to the same object:

```
obj[VARIABLE3]= VARIABLE4;
```

Then do update operation as:

```
db.collectionname.update( { _id: this._id },{ $set: obj } );
```