# Mongoose/Mongodb queries do not work with TypeScript Objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, object, mongoose

I am using Node.js with mongoose together with Typescript. And based on SO threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503656/using-variables-in-mongodb-update-statement) queries should work with my function as well:

```
 let conditions = {};

 conditions['belongsToRestaurant'] = dto.restId;
 conditions['belongsToRestaurant']

    await Order.findOne({conditions}).then((doc) => {
                console.log('doc');
                console.log(doc);
            })
```

The console always logs the proper value for "restId", and always null for "doc".

I have tried every single variation I could think of. I created an object with a constructor, created an object with a set property, tried with classes nothing worked. I tried using mongoose types, such as:

```
conditions['consumerName'] = new mongoose.Schema.Types.String("asasd");
conditions['belongsToRestaurant'] = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(dto.restId);
```

Nothing has worked so far. Thx for reading and help in advance!

- Sidenote: Keep in mind these fields I am referencing are not in array, or in a subdocument or anything of that nature. And work completely fine when I am not using objects to update.

Comment: conditions is already an object and u wrap it in curly braces in findOne which makes it an object inside an object. try removing the curly braces from your findOne function

Comment: Oh wow, I knew when I woke up this day is gon' be tough. Thanks Asaf Aviv ! It worked! :) How do I mark your comment as a resolution to the problem?

Comment: lol, glad to help

Comment: thx, if you can mark your answer as a resolution by any chance go for it. The button does not seem to appear for me for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tiny mistake of wrapping the condition object inside an object.

Removing the wrapping curly braces from the `findOne` function will fix the problem.

```
const conditions = {};
conditions.belongsToRestaurant = dto.restId;

await Order.findOne(conditions)
  .then((doc) => {
    console.log('doc');
    console.log(doc);
  });
```